# SharePoint 2013 out of the box workflow error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, workflow, out-of-the-box

I am the site owner and I have create a 2010 out of the box approval workflow for my site. Whenever I start the workflow, I get a Page not found error. The workflow is running but I land in this error page. Attached is the screen shot. Only I am getting this and not others. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your workflow? Have you tried re-creating your workflow?

Answer (score 1):

When we manually start a 2010 approval workflow, an intiation form will be opened.

The URL of the intiation form of OOB 2010 approval workflow should be:

```
<site url>/_layouts/15/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List=<list GUID>&ID=<item ID>&ItemGuid=<item GUID>&TemplateID=<workflow GUID>&Source=<after completion of this intiation it will redirect to this url>
```

Check the URL of your form when you start the workflow, see if it is correct.

Besides, open it via the URL directly, see if it works.

Navigate to another site collection (or create a new site collection), check whether the issue occurs.

Comment: It was a bug in SharePoint starting a workflow from the new look experience. Works well in the classic experience. Reported it to microsoft.